# WP7 - Determine where the app will go when the "back" button is pressed

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm working on a WP7 appliation with Silverlight. When a user clicks the back button, I want to determine where they will go to. Is there a way to determine where a user will go without managing my own nav stack?

thanks!

Comment: It is usually a good idea to include your reasons for a question.  You have a number of answers addressing an issue which may or may not be your intention.  Either their efforts that have provided  sound advice is useful or they've just wasted their time because assumptions made about your intent are faulty.  More detail in your question would make it more clear which it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To respond to the question that has *actually* been asked "Is there a way to determine where a user will go without managing my own nav stack?"

You could use the `OnNavigatingFrom` override the eventargs of which carries the Uri of the page being navigated to.  I suspect this is only useful when the navigation is back to page within your app.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override what the back button does - the rule Derek mentioned is enforced by the system and the previous page/app will always be called.

You can, however, add an action to be executed on back key press:

```
this.BackKeyPress += new EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs>(MainPage_BackKeyPress);
```

Then just use the handler:

```
void MainPage_BackKeyPress(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   // Your activity goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The application will go back to the previous page when the user presses the Back button. If the user is at the last page in the application, then the application will exit and the user will be navigated to the previous application. To perform anything else would be inconsistent, confusing to the user, and almost certainly would fail certification.

Answer (score 0):

In general you'll want to build your app composed of pages (similar to a website).  For example a HyperlinkButton might be used like this:

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="/Page2.xaml" Content="Click here to enter page 2"/>
```

After clicking that then pressing the back button will automatically return to the previous page.  There's no extra programming involved to make this happen... it just works.

But there are some circumstances where you'll want to override the back button.  The one I ran into was the dialog box.  If your app creates a dialog box, then the back button should close it instead of returning to the previous page.  I wrote a [brief article](http://swortham.blogspot.com/2010/11/windows-phone-7-use-of-back-button.html) about how to accomplish this.

And here's a complete list of rules from [Microsoft's certification requirements](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9730556) concerning the back button:

> To maintain a consistent user
>   experience, the Back button must only
>   be used for backwards navigation in
>   the application.
>
> a. Pressing the Back button from the
>   first screen of an application must
>   exit the application.
>
> b. Pressing the Back button must
>   return the application to the previous
>   page.
>
> c. If the current page displays a
>   context menu or a dialog, the pressing
>   of the Back button must close the menu
>   or dialog and cancel the backward
>   navigation to the previous page.
>
> d. For games, when the Back button is
>   pressed during gameplay, the game can
>   choose to present a pause context menu
>   or dialog or navigate the user to the
>   prior menu screen. Pressing the Back
>   button again while in a paused context
>   menu or dialog closes the menu or
>   dialog.

As I found out, if you don't follow those rules they won't approve your app.